# Accessing jQuery $(this) object on plugin init

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I stacked about accessing `$(this)` object in **[twbsPagination](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/)** pagination plugin.

```
<ul class="dynamic-pagination pagination-sm" data-target="invoices"></ul>
```

On `onPageClick` option, `$(this)` object working perfect!

```
    $('.dynamic-pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 35,
        visiblePages: 7,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            $($(this).attr('data-target')).text('Page ' + page);
        }
    });
```

But on `href` option, `$(this)` doesnt working.

```
    $('.dynamic-pagination').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 35,
        visiblePages: 7,
        href: 'admin?'+$(this).attr('data-target')+'_page={{number}}'
    });
```

I have to access `$(this)` object from `href` option. I couldnt find the solution on web and SO.

Comment: Just a small hint : You're accessing the `this` object from the global scope (or whatever scope your code is within).

Comment: Where have you used your second code? Can you post complete code.

Comment: @Satpal second code mean what?

Comment: @abhishek Hmm, i want to `.dynamic-pagination`'s object, not global. What can i do? Extending `this`?

Comment: @Bora Have you tried wrapping the plugin call in `$('.dynamic-pagination').each()` ? You could then get the `data-target` attribute using `$(this).attr('data-target')`, and call the plugin as `$(this).twbsPagination()` inside the callback.

Comment: @abhishek Great idea! and perfect works! Answer and i'll choose as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows :

```
$('.dynamic-pagination').each(function () {

    var $this = $(this), dataTarget = $this.attr('data-target');

    $this.twbsPagination({

        totalPages: 35,

        visiblePages: 7,

        href: 'admin?' + dataTarget + '_page={{number}}'

    });

});
```